# How do you eat your eggs?

Tags: american-english, british-english

When I was in America I was offered eggs for breakfast as either 'up', 'down', 'easy' or 'dropped'.

None of them are in use in Britain, where we have our eggs, fried, scrambled, boiled, or poached.

Please could someone match these terms for me?

Comment: The waitress was being very terse (probably she was just having some fun). They're usually called "sunny-side up", "sunny side down", and "over easy". I've never heard "dropped", but I wouldn't be surprised if it was either regional in the US, or a term used in restaurants among the staff, but not generally with customers. Where was this.

Comment: Indianapolis. Several years ago.

Comment: Sorry. It may have been Orlando!

Comment: I think she was probably speaking "[diner lingo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diner_lingo)", which undoubtedly has regional variations, but not any I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think...

- up = sunny-side up
- down = sunny-side down
- easy:

> Eggs cooked "over easy" means that it gets fried on both sides, but
>   the yolk stays runny. To make one, you cook the raw egg just until the
>   whites are set on the bottom, then you quickly flip it over to cook
>   the other side. "Over" refers to flipping the egg, and "easy" refers
>   to the doneness of the yolk. You can also cook eggs "over medium" and
>   "over hard," depending on how cooked you prefer the yolk!
>
> [*Source*](http://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-eggs-over-96069)

- dropped = poached

I researched several websites for this.

Comment: Ah. That's what I guessed. Dropped = poached. But how do they say 'scrambled' and how about 'boiled'?

Comment: Is poached different from boiled? :(

Comment: @WS2: [Wrecked?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diner_lingo#W)

Comment: 'Boiled' means in the shell. 3 mins for soft, 5 for hard. Poached is the broken egg cooked in a pan over water.

Comment: But wrecked eggs are somewhat not good to the ears. Haha! This is the first time I learned about this. :D "Wrecked eggs" is not on the menu, though.

Comment: @WS2 Maybe they do not have scrambled and boiled eggs available? Or they just don't usually do it?

Comment: @Peter Shor Do you really say 'wrecked', or do you not eat them 'scrambled' i.e. beaten with a little milk and cooked in a saucepan, or nowadays in the microwave, so that the mixture becomes dry and fluffy. It is often the favourite way with kids.

Comment: I don't say "wrecked", but I don't say "dropped", either. I say "scrambled" and "poached". The terms "wrecked" and "dropped" are ["diner lingo"](http://www.dinerlingo.com/), which is a light-hearted jargon that waiters and waitresses use to communicate with short-order cooks in restaurants. The term "eighty-six" has managed to escape from diner lingo to general American slang, but I don't think either "wrecked" or "dropped" has.

Comment: I first heard the term "wrecked" in a children's book _Frank & Ernest Run a Diner_. (In the _Frank and Ernest_ series, the main characters run a business where they help other business owners get their work done while those owners are breifly out of town. Invariably, they come to realize it'll be harder than they initially thought, because they are unfamiliar with that business' jargon and slang.) This diner experience seems to confirm the accuracy of the author's work. I've never seen _wrecked_ on a breakfast menu, but I imagine most breakfast cooks are familiar with the slang.

Comment: @Peter Shor. So any reasonable waiter should perfectly understand me if I ask for 'poached',or 'scrambled' eggs? How about boiled?

Comment: Generally, Americans ask for eggs 'poached', 'scrambled', 'hard-boiled', 'soft-boiled', 'fried', 'sunny-side up', 'over easy', 'over medium', or 'over hard' (I'm probably leaving some out). I don't think most Americans would understand 'dropped', and they'd have to think to realize that 'up', 'down', and 'easy' mean 'sunny-side up', 'sunny-side down', and 'over easy'. If you just asked for 'boiled eggs', I don't know whether you'd get them 'soft-boiled' (with a runny yolk) or 'hard-boiled'.

Comment: I would never ask for "wrecked" or "dropped" eggs at a restaurant; always "scrambled" or "poached". I wouldn't ask for a "cup o' Joe", either; I would ask for coffee. The slang you heard is not typical waitress-to-customer lingo, except perhaps in cases where one is a regular customer in the restaurant. @Peter - if you asked for "boiled," you'd probably get a question: _"Hard or soft?"_

Comment: well, thanks for the information. I feel better informed. There was only one official reply, and that is from Lester Nubla, who I believe is a Filipino. So I think he merits the green tick. And our thoughts and good wishes are with his country and many of its folk today.

Comment: Isn't sunny side down the same as over easy?  Or does it mean over hard?

Comment: @ChrisSunami I presume sunny side down is the exact same thing as sunny side up, but served upside down.

Comment: @DarrenRinger Unless I'm greatly missing something, an upside-down sunny-side up egg is the exact same thing as an over-easy egg, unless you just flip it when serving it (not when cooking it). And in that case, what is the point? See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fried_egg) (section on United States).

Comment: @ChrisSunami That is evidently the difference - over easy is flipped while still in the skillet, but I'm guessing "sunny side down" means it is flipped only when served on the plate (but cooked sunny side up). What's the point? I don't know, I've never had eggs that way or heard the phrase before this question. Since nobody else has offered a possible answer I can only speculate, anyway.